# Wicket datatable filtering after input field change

Tags: java, javascript, filter, datatable, wicket

In a Wicket application I've got a DefaultDataTable with an extension of SortableDataProvider and a clickable column (extension of AbstractColumn).

The datatable is accompanied by a search field and button, so a user can filter the table (comparing search word and table content).

However, I would prefer a different approach. It would be better if the user doesn't have to click on a button to match results, but that the table will update after each character inserted or deleted to/from the search field (immediate filtering, not after pressing on a button). Furthermore, the parts of the records that match the search word should be underlined or receive a different font color.

I know something like this is possible with Javascript, but I have no clue how to attach the Javascript to a datatable. How can I accomplish this? Or is there a better/alternative way to accomplish what I desire?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: if you want to do something with the displayed values in the DataTable you will need to overide the `newCellItem()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` to add ajax behavior to form components. The ajax is called dependent on the js event specified in the constructor, in this case "onkeyup". You then target the component you what the ajax to re-render, for wicket 4, 5 `target.addComponent(datatable);` for wicket 6x `target.add(datatable);`. But note that the datatable sets its OutputMarkupId true `target.addComponent(datatable);`, this is required for any component being targeted by wicket ajax.

```
datatable.setOutputMarkupId(true); 

field.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeyup") { 
   @Override 
   protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) { 
           target.addComponent(datatable); 
   }
});
```

You may also want [throttling](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxEventBehavior.html#setThrottleDelay%28org.apache.wicket.util.time.Duration%29), hope this helps!

Comment: The update works like a charm, thank you very much. Now I only have to change something about the filtered elements. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: nstead of AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeyup") i would use the `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` which covers also pasting via mouse an so on ...

Comment: @Robert ooo didnt know about the `OnChangeAjaxBehavior`, that does look like the best option. @Attiej what do you need to change in the filtered elements?

Comment: Underlining or changing the colors of the text of the filtered elements. For example: if a users searches for the string 'ab', the characters 'a' en 'b' of the string 'abc' should be underlined (or other css)

Comment: @drobson thats wicket: you fight 3 days with a class only to find out that is has a subclass which already does what oyu want. Had this so many times already ...